# Flutter web: How to hide alert message in the console when the HTTP status codes is failed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-http

I am using the API in Flutter.
Sometimes the server will return failed HTTP status codes and Flutter always auto-generated the alert message with shown the API URL in the console. I don't want to shown the API URL and this alert message makes the app look not complete from the user's perspective. I want to hide these alert messages. How to do that?

Example:
[image]

Comment: This is what browsers usually do, it is not Flutter specific. You can try to use `try/catch` blocks around the code parts that can fail this way and try to suppress these messages. But I would not worry, users in general don't use browser's devtools. Check some famous sites, many of them has plenty on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'This is normal behavior for the browser' By https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112155#issuecomment-1255310351

This is a way that can clear the console -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/73862039/17798537

Answer (score 0):

You can use the try/catch block.

```
try {
  await http.get('...')
  ...
} catch(e) {
  print(e);
}
```

Comment: I used try catch, but this doesn't work. The message still shown in console.